# "ar" command not found in Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

```
root@joker:/usr/libaio# ar -x libaio1*.deb

bash: ar: command not found
```

I was trying to extract a .deb package by using `'ar'` command in my newly installed Debian.
I tried to find how I can install this utility. But not able to find it.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ar  is provided by **binutils**

make sure you have it installed

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with `dpkg`

```
dpkg -x libaio1*.deb /tmp/out
```

Comment: I have tried dpkg and it works .But now i am interested about 'ar'. So i am here.